# AngularJS Custom filter using radio button

Tags: angularjs, toggle, angularjs-filter, radiobuttonlist

```
<div ng-repeat="item in places"> 
 <input type="radio" name="rdnPriority"  value="{{item}}"  ng-checked="exists(item,selected)" ng-click="toggle(item,selected)"  >{{item}}<label>

 var app = angular.module("myModule", ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
 app.controller("GetTicketDetails", function ($scope, $http, $interval) {

 $scope.GetOrders = function () {
                var url = window.location.search;
                url = url.replace("?", ''); // remove the ?
                //alert(url); 

                debugger;
                $http({
                    url: "../api/GetOrderDetailByDate",
                    method: "GET"
                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $scope.ListTicketDetails = response.data;
                    $scope.TotalTickets = response.data.length;

                    $scope.selected = [];
                    $scope.places = [];
                    // when user clicks on checkbox, change selected list
                    $scope.toggle = function (item, list) {

                        var idx = list.indexOf(item);
                        if (idx > -1) list.splice(idx, 1);
                        else list.push(item);
                    };

                    // is item exists in list
                    $scope.exists = function (item, list) {
                        debugger;
                        debugger;
                        if (scope.checked == item) {
                            scope.checked = false;
                        }
                        return list.indexOf(item) > -1;
                    };

                    // process user data and prepare whole places
                    angular.forEach($scope.ListTicketDetails, function (x, key) {
                        if ($scope.places.indexOf(x.OrderStatus) == -1) {
                            //$scope.recordLimit = 5;
                            $scope.places.push(x.OrderStatus);
                        }

                    });
}

 app.filter('SelectedTags', function () {
            // filter to check array of elements
            return function (users, tags) {
                return users.filter(function (x) {
                    if (tags.indexOf(x.OrderStatus) != -1) {
                        return true;
                    } else if (tags.length == 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            };
        })
```

Hello , I have written a AngularJS Custom filter that filters the orders based on status using RadioButton Check . The problem is data is filtering but Radio Button I need to double click one click for Uncheck existing checked and next check othr status . Is there a way i can achieve that with just single check on there options of radio button .

{{Item}} is filtering all orderstatus from array and rendering radio button Inputs options.

Please help

Comment: pls set the data example what `url: "../api/GetOrderDetailByDate",` returns

Comment: ```[
   {
      "OrderId":206,
      "OrderStatus":4,
      "DeliveryCharges":50.00
   },
   {
      "OrderId":201,
      "OrderStatus":4,
      "DeliveryCharges":50.00
   },
   {
      "OrderId":200,
      "OrderStatus":2,
      "DeliveryCharges":50.00
   }
]```